# ViewPager findFragmentByTag returning null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-adapter

I am using FragmentStatePagerAdapter and I need to get the current fragment. So every time I swipe to a new page I need to get some data from that fragment.

So this is what I did on pageChange:

```
  mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                           Log.v("vp id",String.valueOf(mViewPager.getId()));
                           ArticleSwipableObjectFragment fragment = 
                                     (ArticleSwipableObjectFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
                                                  "android:switcher:"+R.id.pager+":"+mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
                                 if(fragment != null)  // could be null if not instantiated yet
                                 {
                                    if(fragment.getView() != null) 
                                    {
                                       String shareUrl = fragment.getShareUrl(); 
                                       android.util.Log.v("share url",shareUrl);
                                    }
                                 }        
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

                   }
           });
```

Though I receive `fragment as null`.

Any suggestions where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
(<yourFragmentType>)pageradapter.getItem(myViewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

that will get the object in the Array that the adapter has a reference to.

Answer (score -3):

Please use Interface and callBack method then resolve your problem.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed idea.